# How to keep track of individual QML object of single QML component?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am new to Qt and QML. I have a QML component like this (filename: GenericComponent.qml, reducted) -

```
Item {
    id: root
    property bool showElement: false

    SometimesVisible { // This is a QML Popup
        visible: root.showElement
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        
        onClicked: {
            root.showElement = !root.showElement
        }
    }

}
```

`GenericComponent.qml` can be reused in different places all over the application. It can be used as different loader's source component which means it can be dynamically created and destroyed.

Now how can I keep the `SometimesVisible`'s visibility state saved so that if someone opens `GenericComponent` after closing it before, SometimesVisible will keep its previous state?

I am thinking about keeping a C++ model where I will register this component and save its visible state. But I am not sure how to identify this component uniquely as `GenericComponent` can be used in different places. Should I approach this problem differently? Please share your opinion.

Please Note: I cant save this in settings because in that case the state will be restored even after the application restart.

I truly haven't tried anything yet because I cant find a way to identify the components uniquely.

Comment: How about creating a singleton C++ config server class, where you can store key/value pairs. Add a name property to your GenericComponent and use this name as the key in your configuration..

Comment: @JürgenLutz That would require for the parent components to pass the name property and they have to make sure its unique, this is a bit problematic because the component can be reused in different places and hierarchies, in list delegate for example. If we keep a default component name then it will not work because the name will be same for two parent component that reuse it.

Comment: Add a key generator function to the config server. Each GenericComponent retrieves a unique key from the server and uses this key for its own management.

Comment: You're going to have to give each instance of GenericComponent a unique name. Even if it's in a ListView, you could make the name something like "listItem1", "listItem2", etc. The problem with automatic key generators in your case seems to be that you can destroy and create new instances on the fly. So they won't be able to remember their own key. So you just have to manually name each instance.